# DVD drive troubleshooting

Tags: windows-vista, dvd, optical-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DVD drive disappears](https://superuser.com/questions/33962/dvd-drive-disappears)

Recently my DVD drive has stopped responding to discs. I've tried to install software like Rosetta Stone and the Adobe Suite. The disk drive doesn't appear on My Computer.

[image]

Comment: SATA or IDE? If you go into your BIOS, does it recognize the drive? Could be a loose cable.

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar Doubtful - in the other one it appears for a short ammount of time. The OP makes no mention of it here.

Answer (score 0):

Does it appear in Device Manager?
To get to Device manager right click My Computer and click manage.
Then select the option that says Device Manager (Windows 7, check the web for alternative OS)
You are looking for this:

[image]

If it does not appear, and you are capable, open up the case (powering computer down first) and check that the DVD drive is correctly connected to the PC. i.e. both the Power and sata (or IDE) cable are plugged in. Also check that the Sata or IDE cable is plugged securely into the Motherboard. If this doesn't get it working try and borrow a similar unit and test it in your machine, if this works then it is likely the drive its-self is bad and needs replacing.

Edit #2: As the drive has power it is just the Data cable you need to check. Just try reseating it at both the DVD Drive end and the Motherboard end.

Comment: How can I tell which disk drive is which when looking in the Device Manager?

Comment: I've found the drive and I've updated the question with a link to an image. The driver software is up to date, I suppose I'll have to open it up now...

Comment: @ambo100 - Have you tried rolling back the drivers? You could also try deleting the device from Windows and seeing if it auto loads the drivers when it restarts. I would try both these things before opening the case.

Comment: @JoeTaylor The option to rollback the driver has been greyed out.

Comment: @ambo100 - Have you tried deleting the device from device manager?

Comment: I have managed to uninstall the drive.

Comment: @Ambo100 - When you restart Windows does the drive reappear in Device manager? Is it the same? If so you are probably best checking the manufacturers website for the drivers as it seems your PC cannot find the correct drivers for your drive

Comment: Have you got the software that came with the drive? Is it this one reviewed here: http://www.cdrlabs.com/Reviews/lg-ggc-h20l-super-multi-blue-blu-ray-disc-hd-dvd-rom/Features.html

Comment: This should be the product support and download page for your model if so: http://www.lg.com/us/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=GGC-H20L&initialTab=drivers&targetPage=support-product-profile

Answer (score 0):

Does the eject button still work?  If so, then it has power.  So next is to check the data cable.  Power off the computer, unplug it, open it, and make sure the data cable is seated securely to the drive AND motherboard.  Close the computer, power it back on.  If it still doesn't work, then it may be a problem with windows, or a failed DVD drive.

Comment: Yes, it will still eject. I've never opened a computer before so I'm a bit cautious about trying that out. I'd like to see if it could be anything else and try and leave that as a last resort.